# How to avoid NULL values in database table using SSIS package creation?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, business-intelligence, ssis-2012

I'm using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development studio - > Integration Service project

My Task is use Excel file as input source . insert the excel sheet values to DB [Destination source] table [SQL 2008]

My Excel Format [I'm using MS-Office 2013]

```
 ID|Tier|TierType|Age|Count
 ==========================
 1   4             18  0.652
 2   4    EV           2.569
 3   5    EG       25  1.035
 .   .    .         .   .
 .   .    .         .   .
 .   .    .         .   .
800  4    EE       40  1.526
```

### My DB Table Design

```
Tier    - int
TierType- varchar(5)
Age     - int
Count   - float
```

### Table output.

```
ID|Tier|TierType|Age|Count
==========================
1   4    NULL     18   0.652
2   4    EV       NULL 2.569
3   5    EG       25   1.035
.   .    .         .   .
.   .    .         .   .
.   .    .         .   .
800 4    EE       40  1.526
```

I'm able to insert excel sheet values insert into DB table successfully.

My problem Is

In excel sheet First 8 records are empty from 9 records onwards values present sample below:-

```
ID|Tier|TierType|Age|Count
==========================
1  
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9  4      EE     20   0.256
```

If first 8 records are empty remaining values also display null for (int[Tier,Age],float[Count]) in DB table.Varchar values Display correctly

### Table output.

```
ID|Tier|TierType|Age|Count
==========================
1   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
2   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
3   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
4   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
5   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
6   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
7   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
8   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
9   NULL  EE     NULL  NULL 
.
.
.
800 NULL  EC     NULL  NULL
```

please tell it's Default problem or i made mistake in creating package.

Comment: Are the first 8 rows Always empty? Does it work when you delete those empty rows?

Comment: @jodyT Sometime First 8 rows have values in decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excel provider uses the first 8 rows to determine the datatypes. ([more info](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/06/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column.html)) You can change that behavior by changing a registry setting on your server, but if the first 8 rows are always empty then you could also use a query on your excel sheet with a range (instead of taking the whole sheet):

SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$ range]

SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:B10]

Comment: I Use IMEX=1 in  Excel Connection string it's Working fine. If any problem Occur due to this...

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Conditional Split Component between your Excel Source and your OLE DB Destination. I would then us an expression in there to detect when you have nulls. If Teir being null is sufficient, your expression would be

```
IsNull([Tier])
```

If you need to check that all the fields are null then you would use the `&&` and operator to make it like

```
IsNull([Tier]) && IsNull([TierType]) && IsNull([Age]) && IsNull([Count])
```

Whatever your business logic is, use this sort of expression to filter out the all empty rows.

An alternative that @JodyT alluded to was that if there are *always* N rows empty, then you can modify your connection manager to skip those rows.